# Fast forward and backward in a song

Tags: music, 8.1

How can I control the position at which the music playback will begin?

For example, I want to hear a snippet of the song and not the entire song - how do I jump to that exact position?

Comment: What do you mean by "forward you there using the music control"?

Comment: @RayCheng I'm in the mood to hear a snippet of the song and not the entire song :) is that how I hear classical music has some that have an hour long and I didn't always want to start listening to her since the beginning

Comment: So you want to fast forward in the song? Simply tap and hold hold down the next track button and the song will skip forward. Release when you want to resume normal playback.

Comment: @Indrek that's thanks, answer on the answer for me to give you a certain and upvote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fast forward in the Music app, simply tap and hold down the next track button, and the song will skip forward. Release when you want to resume normal playback.

To rewind, do the same with the previous track button.

This also works with the playback controls in the Volume Bar that pops up when you press the phone's volume keys.